# Any tutorials or guides for Shopify app development with node?

Tags: node.js, express, shopify, liquid

My company is wanting to migrate their entire site to Shopify. We use node for our backend, so we're hoping to integrate that into the site. I am new though, and not experienced with node or Shopify app development, so I was hoping to find a tutorial or guide, but it seems that almost all resources are specifically for ruby. Is there anything out there I'm just not seeing?

Bonus question:
Is express routing possible on Shopify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The node-shopify-api library](https://github.com/christophergregory/shopify-node-api) has some decent examples as well as being a very useful core of a Node based Shopify app.

Routing is possible only for apps attached at a proxy url.

Comment: Routing is also essential for any App installed in a shop functioning as support for a shop. App Proxy is a small subset of routing, its there, but you can almost certainly find many more examples of Apps without a Proxy than Apps with a Proxy.

You are lucky there are so many Ruby examples out there. Since scripting is scripting is scripting, you want to learn from nicer scripting how to do things. Ruby reads nice, making learning easier. Having example in an uglier language like Javascript or PHP can slow your learning curve of the basic patterns you need to master, regardless the language

Comment: In the context of the question he seemed to be asking about routing actual  shop navigation which does need an application proxy. 

And yes most apps will have plenty of routes not associated with the application proxy url.

Comment: True enough. Trying to shoehorn a Shopify store into a node backend is definitely possible, proven to work, and takes the skills of an expert with both a deep understanding of Shopify, and decent to mad JS skills. Not a beginner project.

Comment: @bknights Can you please answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47432209/shopify-get-shop-domain-inside-a-app